# chrome.runtime.sendMessage not working with Asynchronous calls from Multiple Tabs

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a popup with a button like shown below

[image: popup-image]

I am having a click function like below in popup.js

```
    $('#fetch_article').on('click',()=>{

    chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function(tabs){
        const url=tabs[0].url;

        chrome.storage.local.get(['session_articles'],(data)=>{

            let articles=data.session_articles || [];

            if(articles.length<=0 && Object.keys(articles).length === 0){

                articles.unshift({url:url,state:'Fetching',data:null});
                fetcArticles(url);
                
            }else{

                // Check if URL already exists
                const linkFound = articles.find(link=>link.url===url);

                if(linkFound===undefined){

                    articles.unshift({url:url,state:'Fetching',data:null});  
                    fetcArticles(url);
                }

            }

            chrome.storage.local.set({'session_articles':articles}, function() {
                refreshArticles();
            });
        });
    });
})

function fetcArticles(url){

    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type: "fetch_article",url:url},(response)=>{

        if(response.type==='success'){

            chrome.storage.local.get(['session_articles'],(data)=>{
    
                let articles=data.session_articles;
    
                const linkIndex = articles.findIndex(link=>link.url===response.data.url);
    
                if(linkIndex!==-1){
    
                    articles[linkIndex].state='Done';
                    articles[linkIndex].data={summary:response.data.summary,title:response.data.title};
    
                    chrome.storage.local.set({'session_articles':articles}, function() {
                        refreshArticles();
                    });
    
                }else{
                    console.error("Error in Fetching articles from session");
                }
    
                
            });
        }else{
    
            console.error("Could not Fetch article, So deleting it from storage");
            removerArticleFromStorage(url);
        }
    });

}
```

**In Backgroun.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener( (request, sender, sendResponse) => {

    switch (request.type) {
        case "fetch_article":

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://someajaxurl.com/method",
                data: JSON.stringify({url:request.url}),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(response){
                    
                    if(response.type==='error'){
                    
                        sendResponse({type:'error',msg:response.msg});
                    }else{
                        response.data.url=request.url;
                        sendResponse({type:'success',data:response.data});
                    }

                   
                }
            });
            return true;

            break;
        default:
            sendResponse({type:'error',msg:'Nothing Found Here...'});
            break;
    }
});
```

This works all good if I click the fetch article button and stays in that tab, but if I click the fetch article button in Tab1 and Move to Tab2 The **fetcArticles callback** is not working expectedly. What I am doing wrong here.

Comment: If your popup is a standard browser_action (or page_action) then it automatically closes when you switch tabs so its scripts terminate immediately. You can open the popup or even a dedicated page as a separate window (via chrome.windows.create) to prevent that.

Comment: It is a "browser_action", Can't I achieve this behaviour with this approach and why?

Comment: You can't. Chrome works like I explained above.